# Specific unicode character not displayed properly in python image

Tags: python, fonts

I am trying to create an image with some unicode characters but some of them aren't being displayed properly. You can see in this sample image:

[image]

The character in question I am trying to print is \u2BEA, which is a half star image. Unfortunately the output just shows me the generic missing character icon.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

output_image = Image.new('RGB', (200,100), (0,0,0))
text = '\u2605\u2605\u2605\u2BEA\u2606'
font = ImageFont.truetype("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\yugothb.ttc", 18)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output_image)
draw.text((10, 10), text, (255,255,255), font=font)
output_image.show()
```

Note: you may need to adjust the font location for your computer

In my sample code I'm using the Yu Gothic Bold font and not getting the correct output. I have tried using other fonts such as Arial and Calibri, which produced even worse results.

My thought process is that the character isn't part of of the font but I have yet to find a font that supports it.

Does anyone know of a free font that I can use that will display this character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode `'u2BEA'` defined as "STAR WITH LEFT HALF BLACK", but not defined in any font file on my platform.

Maybe you can download and use following font files,

- BabelStone Han
  https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Download/BabelStoneHan.ttf
- Symbola
  https://dn-works.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/UFAS-Fonts/Symbola.zip
- Unifont
  https://unifoundry.com/pub/unifont/unifont-13.0.06/font-builds/unifont-13.0.06.ttf

Note: Last one with large font than `'\u2605'` and `'\u2606'`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using BableStone Han. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any font that includes `\u2BEA` or `\u2BE8` (ref: https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2B00.html#2BEA), but the following icons by Font Awesome might meet your needs: [Star Icon (Solid)](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/star?style=solid) [Stat Half Alt Icon (Solid)](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/star-half-alt?style=solid) [Star Icon (Regular)](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/star?style=regular)

In Font Awesome, `f005` refers to the 'star' icon, and `f5c0` refers to the 'star-half-alt' icon.

So, you can [download Font Awesome Free for Desktop](https://fontawesome.com/download) at https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/fontawesome-free-5.15.3-desktop.zip, then draw solid `\uF005\uF005\uF005\uF5C0` with 'Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf' and a single hollow star `\uF005` with 'Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf'.

The following works properly:

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

output_image = Image.new('RGB', (200,100), (0,0,0))
solid = ImageFont.truetype('fontawesome-free-5.15.3-desktop/otfs/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf', 18)
regular = ImageFont.truetype('fontawesome-free-5.15.3-desktop/otfs/Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf', 18)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output_image)
draw.text((10, 10), '\uF005' * 3 + '\uF5C0', (255,255,255), font=solid)
draw.text((90, 10), '\uF005', (255,255,255), font=regular)
output_image.show()
```

[image]